# Typescript, assigning Inpur or Textarea?

Tags: html, typescript, input, textarea

Based on passing "textarea" prop, I want to render `textarea` instead of `input` but I am getting this error in typescript:

```
Type 'ComponentWithAs<"textarea", TextareaProps>' is not assignable to type 
'ComponentWithAs<"input", InputProps>'.   Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
```

Here is the component

```
type InputFieldProps = InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  // If I pass this prop, I want to render textarea
  textarea?: boolean;
};

// size is one input attrs and passing it to Input, ts was complaining
export const InputField: React.FC<InputFieldProps> = ({
  label,
  textarea,
  size: _, //ts compains the format that passed to INput. since i dont use it, i stripped i toff
  ...props
}) => {
  let InputOrTextarea = Input;
  if (textarea) {
    InputOrTextarea = Textarea;
  }
 
  const [field, { error }, helpers] = useField(props); 
  return (
    // isINvalid type is boolean.
    <FormControl isInvalid={!!error}>
      <FormLabel htmlFor={field.name}>{label} </FormLabel>
      <InputOrTextArea
        {...props}
        {...field}
        id={field.name}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      />
      {error && <FormErrorMessage>{error}</FormErrorMessage>}
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
 let InputOrTextArea:
    | ComponentWithAs<"input", InputProps>
    | ComponentWithAs<"textarea", InputProps> = Input;
  if (textarea) {
    // @ts-ignorets-ignore
    InputOrTextArea = Textarea;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is that I casted Textarea from chakra as any

```
let InputOrTextarea = Input;

  if (textarea) {
    InputOrTextarea = Textarea as any;
  }
```

I am guessing, not sure but it's because not all props are matching between these two component the Input and Textarea from chakra so you are getting an error. For some reason when you set InputOrTextarea to Input, and you want to assign it again it is expecting this type of component

```
InputOrTextarea: ComponentWithAs<"input", InputProps>
```